# can't see input in input box for react/html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am working on a react app for a portfolio builder and when I run it I can't see anything I type into my input boxes.  Can someone please take a look and let me know why this is?  Really appreciated.  Thanks!!  I have correctly cased my onChange, which I've seen can be a problem, but I don't understand why this isn't working.

```
class Login extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
    };
  }


handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  //console.log("submit selected");
  const userData = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    };
    this.props.loginUser(userData, this.props.history);
  };



  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };

render() {
 return (
    <div className = "sign-in">
      <Topbar />
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input
        type = "text"
        placeholder="Email"
        value={this.state.email}
        onChange = {this.handleChange}
        />

        <input
        type = "password"
        placeholder= "Password"
        value={this.state.password}
        onChange = {this.handleChange}
        />

        <button type = "submit"> Sign In </button>
      </form>

    </div>
  );
}
}
```

Comment: This is setting state for `event.target.name` but the target which is the input doesn't have a `name` attribute.

Comment: That was it.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the handleChange you are getting the state from the name of the target, but the target has no name (inputs in html)